# На сколько раз увеличится скорость отрисовки в cycles render?

Tags: cuda, blender, render, gpu, nvidia

У меня на компьютере стоит видеокарта "NVIDIA GeForce GT 220" у него "compute capability 1.6". А программа который я использую Blender поддерживает видеокарты с compute capability от 2.0 до 6.1, так написано на оффициальном сайте blender. Как вы узнали мою видеокарту не поддерживает. А теперь сам вопрос, на сколько раз увеличится отрисовка на cycles render, если поставлю видеокарту "GTX 1080 ti" у него compute capability как раз 6.1 а CUDA ядер 3584. Я эту видеокарту хочу купить и для того чтобы играть 3D игры. На сколько раз  увеличится скорость и как вы считаете? Или напишите у кого с конкретной видеокартой работает на сколько-то раз быстрее.
Скриншот.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По моему опыту в cycles, хорошая видеокарта сильно увеличивает скорость отрисовки, а тем более с ядрами cuda. К сожалению точно сказать не получиться, но судя по [этому бенчмарку](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1080-Ti-vs-Nvidia-GeForce-GT-220/3918vsm7737), скорость возрастёт раза в 2,5 - 3;

Comment: А у вас какой видеокарта стоит, очень интересно. Я думал что "GTX 1080 ti" 300 раз быстрее а не 3 раза

Comment: Как считаю если CUDA ядер 48 то 3 раза быстрее, если CUDA ядер 3584 то очень быстро должен быть. Или на это не смотрят

Comment: Вы посмотрели бенчмарк? Не думаю что какая либо видеокарта сможет ускорить процесс в 300 раз. Однако я могу ошибаться.

Comment: При чем здесь старая видеокарта, если она не поддерживается?

Comment: Я написал свою видеокарту потому что, люди у кого видеокарта "GT 220" знали что Compute Capability этой видекарты 1.6 и им надо менять видеокарту с Compute Capability от 2.0 до 6.1 если хотят ускорить процес рендеринга, программа Blender поддерживает видекарты с Compute Capability от 2.0 до 6.1

Comment: А мне удалось узнать Compute Capability своей видеокарты вот таким вот случайным образом. На моем компьютере стояло программа  Blender 2.79b в настройках этой программы мою видеокарту вообще не показывает. Потом установил чуть старую версию программы Blender 2.59, в настройках показывает мою видеокарту "GT 220", выбираю её, потом в окне настройках рендеринга выбираю GPU, нажимаю на кнопку рендерить, появляется всплываюшая окно с надписью, Compute Capability вашей видеокарты 1.6 а мы поддерживаем видеокарты с Compute Capability от 2.0 до 6.1

Comment: Вот полный список видеокарт который поддерживает программа Blender. https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Answer (score 0):

На ваш вопрос ответить нельзя. Если ваша видеокарта не поддерживается, значит вы рендерите не на GPU, a на процессоре, описание которого вы не дали. 
Но что касается конкретики, мой довольно старый 4-х ядерный процессор с частотой 2.5 ГГц оказывается примерно в 100 раз медленнее GTX 1070

Comment: Да рендеринр происходит на процессоре. Но я на одном ноутбуке проверил, сейчас точно не знаю модель этой видеокарты, помню у него CUDA ядер был 48, а модель самого ноутбука Lenovo 20150, на GPU рендерился ровно на 3 раза быстрее, из этого у меня вывод, если CUDA ядер 48 на 3 раза быстрее, то CUDA ядер 3584 должен быть минимум 100 раз быстрее. Я сам точно не знаю. Этим ещё хочу сказать что я имею маленький опыт о рендеринге на видеокерте

Comment: Кроме количества ядер существует еще много параметров способных повлиять непредсказуемым образом, скорость ядер, их тип, скорость видеопамяти и тд